# Return image in header

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-headers

So I have this code, which im trying to return an existing picture. Though it won't display.
Chrome says server closed the connection unexpectedly, firefox says there's an error in the immage.

This is the code ;

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] img = enc.GetBytes(response);
            Response.AddHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "Chunked");
            Response.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            Response.AddHeader("Keep-Alive", "timeout=1, max=64");
            Response.BinaryWrite(img);

var content = fileStorage.readFile(src); // this is the file. Which is return in response
```

// edit I can't post image.

Comment: What exactly is the response object? I can't find a lower-case-r readFile in the .NET API. Is there another way you can convert it to bytes? I expect `ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes()` is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a little confused with the relationship between the response and content variables.

What is the purpose of the TransferEncoding header? Taking this out makes it work with using a simple:

```
var content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\path\\image.gif")
```

and passing this in the BinaryWrite works.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [HttpResponse.WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyfzssz9.aspx). Using it probably solves it.

Comment: Have to mark this as answer too, because although I didn't try it, it will probably work too. 

EDIT - Hmm you can only have one answer?

Comment: @Quincy yes, only one accepted answer - but (once you get 15 rep) you can vote up all helpful answers.